# Create Docusign envelope from template json file

Tags: c#, json, docusignapi

I'm trying to find a way to use the docusign template creator to easily create complex documents and then download the json template file to use it on our c# application.

The reason for this is to minimize management of templates on the docusign website and just send the already created json template on the fly.

Their documentation shows that you can do either call template or generate on the fly by hardcoding the envelope.

Can the JSON file be reused to create dynamic documents?

Comment: If you want to use template for creating envelopes then those templates have to be present in DocuSign. While creating envelopes, you refer to templateId and DocuSign reads this templateId from DocuSign only.

Comment: Yeah that is how we do it right now.  But I was hoping to use their template creator to simplify the coding process and remove their templating system altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for anyone that might want to do this in the future...

All I did was download the template json file from docusign and just deserialized it to an Envelope Definition.

```
var definition = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnvelopeDefinition>(new StreamReader(path).ReadToEnd());
```

This gives you complete access to the envelope with the json information and you can edit and send.  I updated the TempltaeId to string.Empty to make sure it's not using templates on the docusign website.